Why can component names in Vue only be shadowed by non-default exports?
I have a simple App, that only renders my TestComp. In the setup context of App.vue, there is also a ref called testComp. Even though I am not using the recommended Template Expression of <TestComp /> (and instead <test-comp />), everything renders fine.
<!-- App.vue -->

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import TestComp from './TestComp.vue'

const testComp = ref(null)

</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <test-comp />
    <!-- Recommended is <TestComp />, and this avoids the issue, but not the focus here -->
  </div>
</template>

<!-- TestComp.vue -->
<script setup>

</script>
<template>
  <div>
    I am a test component.
  </div>
</template>

// components.ts
import TestComp from './TestComp.vue'
// supposed to group multiple component definitions together
export {
  TestComp
}

Vue SFC Playground
So the Template Expression <test-comp /> is evaluated as the imported component TestComp and not my variable testComp.
Instead of importing TestComp directly, we can use a file that is grouping my component definitions by importing and re-exporting them in an object. We can achieve that by replacing the import:
from: import TestComp from './TestComp.vue'
to: import { TestComp } from './components.ts'.
Now the Template Expression <test-comp /> seems to be evaluated to the ref testComp, and I get a warning: [Vue warn]: Invalid vnode type when creating vnode: null - the component is not rendered.

Why is there a difference between TestComp being imported directly, and being part of another files non-default export?

FYI - <Test-comp/> also "fixes" the issue

I don't think this is related to default/named import, you get the same result when components.ts uses default export. My guess is that Vue has a prevalence when resolving component names in SFC templates, something like: first check against your own name, then check if there is an import from another SFC, then check variables bound to the template (refs), then check other variables, finally check global components. Together with kebap/camel/pascal case conversion, this can get iffy. Don't know where this is documented.

SFC is a made-up format and works in unspecified way. "script setup" is not spec-compliant JS but some made-up language. So you have a riddle wrapped in an enigma, and the answer is "it works the way it works". In the most favorable case it's described here, https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/ , but it doesn't look like that.   Also the conversion between pascal and kebab in template compiler is stable, but the way it works with camel, etc is undetermined, you shouldn't rely on it at all.

If the problem is that "testComp" was intended as template ref and accidentally shadowed a component, this is a problem with naming convention. You can use testCompRef to make it trouble-free and unambiguous.
